# Rave Report programmatically get pagesize

Tags: delphi, rave-reports

When rendering reports in rave, I can set paper size in RvNDRWriterBeforePrint with (Sender as TBaseReport).SetPaperSize.
In stead of hard coding the paper size, I would rather extract the designed PageHeight and PageWidth from the report definition.
How do I get access to those?

I wonder why this does not work out of the box. My report is a 75x75mm (custom) label, but when it enters RvNDRWriterBeforePrint, the TBaseReport page dimensions corresponds to standard Letter size, and when I select printer and bin, it is changed to the printers default size.

Then I can hard-code the pagesize, but that does not make sense IMHO.